# Python: Spyder IDE wont run simple Hello World

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I am new to programming as well as Python and just recently installed Anaconda and tried running a simple print('Hello world') in from the Spyder editor. By the way I installed Python 3.5.

The code works just fine in the console window, but when I press run after saving, I get the following error:

after setting Spyder to run code in new console window

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory

After setting Spyder to run code from current console window

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any ideas on how to fix this? I don't have the same problem when running code on Jet Brains PyCharm

Comment: I finally figured out the issue. I had previously installed  Jet Brains PyCharm (Pro version) which expired. So that must have somehow affected Spyder.